# How do I install snipMate?

Tags: linux, vim, snippets

I have downloaded snipMate.zip form [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). The install instruction says that:

- unzip it and paste it in `.vim` directory.
- There should be `:filetype plugin on` in .vimrc file

I have did both but non of the snippets are working. This is the first time I'm installing any plugin.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you installed it. You wrote you unzipped it and pasted *it* in your .vim directory. SnipMate.vim contains several files in seven directories. Are you sure you got all the files in the right directories? It's usually best to move a file such as snipMate.zip into your ~/.vim directory first and unzip it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the snipMate directory that you get after unzipping directly inside `~/.vim`? Like that: `~/.vim/snipMate`?

It's its *content* that you have to put into `~/.vim`:

```
.vim
├── after
│   └── plugin
│       └── snipMate.vim
├── autoload
│   └── snipMate.vim
├── doc
│   └── snipMate.txt
├── ftplugin
│   └── html_snip_helper.vim
├── plugin
│   └── snipMate.vim
├── snippets
│   ├── autoit.snippets
│   ├── cpp.snippets
│   ├── c.snippets
│   ├── html.snippets
│   ├── javascript.snippets
│   ├── java.snippets
│   ├── mako.snippets
│   ├── objc.snippets
│   ├── perl.snippets
│   ├── php.snippets
│   ├── python.snippets
│   ├── ruby.snippets
│   ├── sh.snippets
│   ├── _.snippets
│   ├── snippet.snippets
│   ├── tcl.snippets
│   ├── tex.snippets
│   ├── vim.snippets
│   └── zsh.snippets
└── syntax
    └── snippet.vim
```

After that, put this line in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
```

and run this command in Vim to make the snipMate doc available:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

If you do all that, you should be able to read the snipMate doc, which you should do before anything else:

```
:help snipmate
```

Good luck.

Comment: You were right!